# Applying for Schengen Visa in Seattle?

Tags: visas, schengen, seattle

Has anyone applied for Schengen tourist visa from Seattle? I don't want to travel to SFO to apply for the visa. Is there a easy way to get the visa from Seattle?

I am planning to travel to Italy and Greece…

Edit: I am an Indian citizen but permanent resident (green card holder).

Comment: What's your citizenship? and if you need a visa where do you intend to fly?

Comment: If you can enter Canada easily (and presumably, return to the U.S. easily), perhaps a consulate in Vancouver would be more convenient? It's a long drive, but shorter than the drive to San Francisco and probably cheaper than a flight.

Comment: @choster There are plenty Schengen zone consulates in Seattle but if the port of entry doesn't match it may not matter.  Also depends what passport is OP traveling under for entry into Canada.

Comment: @Karlson As far as I can tell, the Schengen zone consulates in Seattle are only honorary consulates and do not have the authority to issue visas.

Comment: @choster You may be right on not being able to issue visas....

Comment: If you had a Schengen visa in the past, you might be able to get a permission to apply for a visa by mail.

Comment: What was the best option eventually? I am in Portland and do not want to travel to SFO either. Indian with Green Card. Thanks. Amit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply for the Schengen visa at either the consulate of the country you plan to stay the longest at, or if staying at all countries equally, at the port of entry.

For the Italian consulate in San Francisco, there is an option to mail your 'verified' documents instead of appearing for the interview.

> YOU MUST APPEAR IN PERSON to apply for a VISA or you may submit your application to the Honorary Consul for a prescreening and then mail it to the Consulate General.

[Italian consular website](http://www.conssanfrancisco.esteri.it/Templates/PaginaInterna.aspx?NRMODE=Published&NRNODEGUID=%7BDCA8094D-B007-46F8-B88B-DD489437EBDE%7D&NRORIGINALURL=/Consolato_SanFrancisco/Menu/I_Servizi/Per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/&NRCACHEHINT=NoModifyGuest)

If you have any further questions, you could email them. They respond within a day usually in my experience.

I could not find any similar option in the Greece consulate in San Francisco.

[Greek Consular website](http://www.mfa.gr/usa/en/services/services-for-non-greeks/visa-section.html)